# How to load FBX in Irrlicht?

Tags: c++, ios, fbx, irrlicht

I make 3D render by Irrlicht engine in iPhone, but it doesn't load FBX file. Although I find the irrAssimp to solve it, I can't load skeletal animation.

Comment: [Possible workaround](https://github.com/JLouis-B/IrrAssimp/issues/3#issuecomment-138100609).

Comment: "... *import your fbx in Blender and I re-export it in fbx, it works. Edit : Not sure, but you can also try to keyframe all your bones (with also the bones that you don't use in the animation) on at least one keyframe can potentially fix this bug.*". Does not always work (not sure why).